# Python muliple deepcopy behaviors

Tags: python, deep-copy

Suppose I have two classes, say `Manager` and `Graph`, where each Graph has a reference to its manager, and each Manager has references to a collection of graphs that it owns. I want to be able to do two things

1) Copy a graph, which performs a deepcopy except that the new graph references the same manager as the old one.

2) Copy a manager, which creates a new manager and also copies all the graphs it owns.

What is the best way to do this? I don't want to have to roll my own deepcopy implementation, but the standard `copy.deepcopy` doesn't appear to provide this level of flexibility.

Comment: You kind of do have to roll your own. It needs a rule-based copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no other objects referenced in graph (just simple fields), then `copy.copy(graph)` should make a copy, while `copy.deepcopy(manager)` should copy the manager and its graphs, assuming there is a list such as `manager.graphs`.

But in general you are right, the `copy` module does not have this flexibility, and for slightly fancy situations you'd probably need to roll your own.

Comment: Sorry, but graph is actually a complicated structure with lots of objects and cyclic references. I would use shallow copy if I could.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this by looking at the `memodict` passed to the `__deepcopy__` special method:

```
class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, manager=None):
        self.manager = None if manager is None else weakref.ref(manager)
    def __deepcopy__(self, memodict):
        manager = self.manager()
        return Graph(memodict.get(id(manager), manager))

class Manager(object):
    def __init__(self, graphs=[]):
        self.graphs = graphs
        for g in self.graphs:
            g.manager = weakref.ref(self)
```

I'm assuming here that you're using `weakref.ref` to break the cycle between `Graph` and `Manager`; if you're using something else then adjust as appropriate.

```
>>> m = Manager([Graph(), Graph()])
>>> mc = copy.deepcopy(m)
>>> [g.manager() is mc for g in mc.graphs]
[True, True]
>>> copy.deepcopy(m.graphs[0]).manager() is m
True
```

Comment: I'm just using normal references. No need to mess around with weak references when you have garbage collection, though memory usage isn't an issue in this case anyway.

Comment: @Antimony oh, fine. Well, it works with normal references; just remove the `weakref.ref` and change `.manager()` to `.manager`.

Comment: Do you have any information about overloading `__deepcopy__`? The docs don't appear to explain how you actually do it, just saying that it's possible.

Comment: @Antimony it takes a `memodict` from `id` of input instances to the deepcopied instance, and should return a deepcopied instance.  Also if you call `deepcopy` from within `__deepcopy__` you should propagate the memodict as an extra argument to `deepcopy`.

Answer (score 0):

What about something really simple like defining the copy protocol for the class?

```
import copy

class Graph(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [1,2,3]
        self.manager = None

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            'data': self.data,
            'manager': self.manager
        }

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.manager = state.pop('manager')
        for name, val in state.iteritems():
            setattr(self, name, copy.copy(val))


class Manager(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [4,5,6]
        self.graphs = []

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            'data': self.data,
            'graphs': self.graphs
        }

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.graphs = [copy.copy(g) for g in state.pop('graphs')]
        for name, val in state.iteritems():
            setattr(self, name, copy.copy(val))
```

You would just define the manager to be a reference and everything else to get copied the way you want.

Example:

```
In [2]: m1 = Manager()

In [3]: g1 = Graph()

In [4]: g1.manager = m1

In [5]: g2 = copy.copy(g1)

In [6]: g2.manager is g1.manager
Out[6]: True

In [7]: g2.data is g1.data
Out[7]: False

In [8]: m1.graphs.extend([g1,g2])

In [9]: m2 = copy.copy(m1)

In [10]: m2.data is m1.data
Out[10]: False

In [11]: m2.graphs[0] is m1.graphs[0]
Out[11]: False

In [12]: m2.graphs[0].manager is m1.graphs[0].manager
Out[12]: True
```